# First-order logic validity question

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I'm a beginner learning first-order logic and I have a couple of difficulties understanding the following question:

"Let L be a first order language with just one predicate, =, and no constants or function symbols. Let A be a sentence that is valid in a structure M if and only if M has at least n elements in its domain. What is the smallest number of variables required to write such a sentence A?"

How should the whole problem be written or structured? Based on my intuition I think the solution is n, because it makes sense that if I were to assign each element to a single variable, decreasing the number of elements (but keeping the variable referring to essentially nothing) would invalidate the sentence. I only have binary marks and no explanations/mark schemes so I'd like to understand how to approach this question since I'm only working on a theory!

Comment: Where did you come across this question? There is a quantifier-elimination process for (an extension of) the pure predicate calculus with equality that leads to an answer.

Comment: It was set as an assignment for beginner computer science students. The question is only worth a single point and it's multiple choice but I'd like to understand it anyway!

Comment: I believe you are right that the answer is $n$ (Henno's answer is addressing a slightly different question). However, the only techniques I can think of for proving this are outside the scope of a beginning CS course. Have you asked your teachers for help?

Answer (score 1):

For $n=3$ I would for example use the formula:

$$\exists x: \exists y: \exists z: \lnot(x=y) \land \lnot(x=z) \land \lnot(y=z) \land \left(\forall u: (u=x) \lor (u=y) \lor (u=z)\right)$$

which uses $4$ variables. So $n+1$ suffices for a model of exact size $n$. I cannot show that fewer cannot suffice, though. Maybe others have ideas for that.

**added** for at least $n$, only the first part is needed. And then I need $n$ variables plus a lot of not equal clauses. I don't see how we could do it with fewer but again, no proof for that.

Comment: This may just be my awfulness at logic but does each variable x, y, z refer to a different element? Is it possible for them each to refer to the same thing? Why exactly does this formula become invalid when we decrease the number of elements?

Comment: @Hiraphor yes, That’s why we need to state $\lnot(x=y)$ explicitly.

Comment: Could I ask why the u is necessary in this formula?

Comment: @Hiraphor only in the exactly 3 case, not in the at least 3 case.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really cleared it up for me

Comment: I don't see how this answer actually answers the question.